# How to add linked Oracle server to SQL 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle-11g

I have tried to download Oracle Client 11g both 32 & 64 packages to Windows 2008 R2 with SQL server 2008 Express. However, I still cannot see Oracle provider in SQL server by using sa log in. Not sure if is it possible to do it for SQL Server express 2008? Any advice to do it?

I followed installations from this article:  [Making Linked Server Connection Between SQL Server 64 Bit & Oracle 32 Bit  | MS SQL World](http://thiruna.blog.com/2010/10/28/making-linked-server-connection-between-sql-server-64-bit-oracle-32-bit/)

After installation and reboot the Windows, I still cannot see the Oracle provider in linked provider in SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem when I was trying to create LinkedServer with Oracle 11g. My oracle instance name was: **PC-2.my.xgen** and my listener name was "**NB**". The last parameter of first statement is actually the concatenation of Oracle server instance and listener name.

So I have write down the following statements in SQL server.

```
--add a linked server into SQL server
--last parameter contains OracleInstance / Listener Name of desired database
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   'OracleLinkedServer4', 'Oracle',   'MSDAORA', 'PC-2.my.xgen/nb'

--add login information into linked server
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'OracleLinkedServer4', false,  Null, 'system',  '123456'
```

In Oracle database "NB" I have a table named : CRD_CIL_NOTIFICATION_TYPE. So I have written down the following statement to get the records.

```
select * from OracleLinkedServer4..SYSTEM.CRD_CIL_NOTIFICATION_TYPE
```